# Getting textual summary of changes from multiple checkins from Subversion repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Let me preface this by saying I'm rather new to source control, so I may misuse some terms terribly here.

I'm trying to get a textual diff summary of the net result of multiple checkins. So, for example, for checkins "Checkin1" and "Checkin2", I'd like to see something like:

> file: \foo.txt removed line 75
>
> line 64, "goodbye" replaced with "hello"
>
> file: \bar.txt removed lines 30-50

I'm very flexible about the format - it really just has to be understandable by a human and it has to be one large contiguous piece of text rather than an interactive UI thing (it's going into a Word document). I need to be able to ignore whitespace changes, as these are irrelevant to my output.

I've been using TortoiseSVN, and what I'm after looks a *lot* like TortoiseSVN's "show changes as unified diff" feature. However, that unified diff unfortunately does not ignore whitespace changes, so I end up with giant diffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of Subversion command line commands that you might find handy:

```
svn log -v
```

This will list the commands and the first line will list `D` and `A` when files are added or deleted from the repository.

For files that have been modified, you can use this command:

```
svn diff -r($rev-1):$rev $fileName
```

And that will list the changes in standard diff format. This will give you the line numbers and the changes on those lines.

There are no already built tools that will format the things the way you want, but it should be possible to create a Perl or Python script in a few hours.

This seems an unusual request. Developers can easily understand the output of diffs and logs, so this isn't for developers. Yet, those who aren't developers aren't going to understand *Delete file 'qualityServiceBeanSkel.java* and *Changed "float morphObjectScan" to "double morphObjectScan"*.

Comment: This is useful - I might try and write a script. To add a bit more info - this isn't really for developers; I'm tracking difference to XML schemas which will ultimately make their way into a printed version of an international standard. All other changes to the text of the standard are tracked in Word documents, so we have to have a way to track the schema changes in there too.

Comment: I managed to make an svn command that worked well for this, and included all the files in my subfolder in a nice list: svn diff -r129:131 -x --ignore-eol-style "C:\myrepos\\*.*" >c:\temp.txt